# Difference between ERC 20 and ERC 721 transaction receipt

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, erc-20, erc-721

I want to fetch certain transaction logs from a local ethereum node. For that, I need to identify how to differentiate between ERC 20 and ERC 721 transaction receipts. From what I saw on Etherscan, i couldn't find any differentiating method as both the receipts look similar. The link of an ERC 20 transaction receipt is here https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbad497f6d96dd111c221ce41355cbb9ac912a6c0953ccb94113ba8232ab95e0a and ERC 721 transaction receipt is https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ae8ba8417d6603e4f0b930b768814883af2d0ee091bc78145e871171768710e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the `Transfer` event prototype on each standard:

- ERC20: `event Transfer(address, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)`
- ERC721: `event Transfer(address, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId)`

These two signatures are indeed the same when you hash them for the purpose of locating `Transfer` events in the ledger using (for example):

```
receipt.topics[0] == Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
```

However, note that each one of them has a different number of `indexed` parameters.

Therefore, you can determine if a `transfer` receipt is ERC20 or ERC721 as follows:

- ERC20: `receipt.topics.length == 1`
- ERC721: `receipt.topics.length == 2`

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer here seems legit but it did not work out for me, so I will list the changes that worked out for me:

First the correct function definitions:

- The ERC20 event: `Transfer(index_topic_1 address from, index_topic_2 address to, uint256 value)`
- The ERC721 event: `Transfer(index_topic_1 address from, index_topic_2 address to, index_topic_3 uint256 tokenId)`

And these can be viewed on the logs page of Etherscan of the transactions in your question.

Hashing both of them by keccak256 would give the same hash as explained in the first answer: `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`

Inside a Transaction receipt, there is the logs array which includes the topics array, the first topic (topics[0]) have the function signature which is the hash above, then the other topics are the indexed parameters.
Therefore, the transactions can be differentiated by the following:

- **ERC20:** `topics.length == function signature + 2 indexed topics == 3`
- **ERC721:** `topics.length == function signature + 3 indexed topics == 4`