# Identifying ERC-721, ERC-777, & ERC-223 Contracts in the EVM via eth.getTransactionReceipts(), etc

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, erc-223, erc-777

Is there any specific way of identifying ERC-721, ERC-777, & ERC-223 contract events under the EVM, specifically under the `eth.getTransactionReceipt()` function?

I know there's a way for ERC-20 tokens by filtering for the `Transfer` keccak-256 hash:

```
0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
```

A brute-force example I could use for CryptoKitties is also filtering for the `'DepositKittyAndMintToken'` hash, yet obviously there are many more ERC-721 token events than just CryptoKitties:

```
0x999fa95b06ad12b3436bab902713e383705707923f9d7c75f5432b28a6487010
```

I'm running a program that runs two loops: through each `transactionHash` under each block, and trying to separate all ERC-20, ERC-721, ERC-777, and ERC-223 token events, yet only have it working for ERC-20's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/80285/16043).

Comment: Oh wow, this is great, thanks! The only discrepancy is I see ERC-20 events with a receipt.topics.length == 3 not 1, while ERC-721's are receipt.topics.length == 1. I just verified on my Geth archive node for a handful of ERC-20 & CryptoKitties transactions, and this appears to be the case.

Comment: Then they are not standard ERC20 event **by definition**.

Answer (score 0):

For ERC-721 and modern contract types that support ERC-165 this can be done using introspection.

The basic way to do it (implementation here shown with Node + Ethers) is:

```js
// Use ERC-165 to check if contract is ERC-721, try/catch in case contract does not support ERC-165
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, erc165Abi, provider);
let isErc721 = 0;
try {
    isErc721 = await contract.supportsInterface(erc721Id) ? 1 : 0;
} catch (error) {
    // Contract does not support ERC-165
}
```

This is excerpted from a full implementation you can study at https://github.com/fulldecent/contract-scanner/blob/main/index.mjs

Also, I have narrated and explain every line of code here if you want to dig deeper, see https://youtu.be/lukshxTYpUw and I have office course ("Community Service Hour") to answer any questions.

Answer (score -1):

...and just like that, came across this:

https://medium.com/axionable-ai-and-blockchain/token-ercs-in-ethereum-erc-20-erc-223-erc-777-and-erc-721-8176c0f11c18