# Determine if transaction receipt is for ERC20 or ERC721

Tags: web3js, transactions, erc-721

I am trying to distinguish between NFT transactions and any other transaction. I found [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80285/difference-between-erc-20-and-erc-721-transaction-receipt) post where it says to compare the topics length, but that seems to be incorrect. ERC721 topic lengths are 4 not 2, but that aside I am still getting transactionReceipts that are from other things. Is there a better way of comparing the incoming log and seeing whether it is specifically for a ERC721 transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please inspect the contract using ERC-165.

This is a requirement of ERC-721 contracts specifically to help you distinguish this.

---

So here is the workflow:

1. Load Transfer event
2. Check if the contract supports ERC-721 (via ERC-165)
3. If yes, it is an ERC-721 transfer
4. If no, it is an ERC-20 transfer

And the step #2 result can be cached.

Comment: What do you mean using ERC-165, could you be a little more specific I'm very new to this space.

Comment: See this for instance: https://medium.com/@chiqing/ethereum-standard-erc165-explained-63b54ca0d273

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth What I took away from that article is that, smart contracts can create some interface that can let other contracts know what functions it implements. Though I'm not sure how this would help with my question.

Comment: @justanotherguy Updated the answer to be more prescriptive

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Is it possible to inspect a contract using ERC165 with web3.js ? I tried looking in the docs and did some searching online but couldn't find anything in relation to that.

Comment: Yes. This is not a built-in feature of Web3. But if you read ERC-165 this should be simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The original post you quoted is a good way to distinguish between the two. An ERC20 transfer will have one less topic than a ERC721 transfer.
2 topics vs 3 topics.

Answer (score 0):

William Entriken's answer is incomplete. Simply checking for ERC165 isn't sufficient because some non ERC-721 standard tokens may also implement ERC165. Here's such an [example](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b0b3a982b4634ac68dd83a4dbf02311ce324181#code) where you can see ERC-165 being implemented but the token is [not ERC-721](https://erc721validator.org/?address=0x6B0b3a982b4634aC68dD83a4DBF02311cE324181).

You'd have to couple the ERC-165 filter along with the interfaces / functions / metadata extensions / enumerable extensions that were introduced with ERC-721 in order to properly filter for ERC-721 tokens. As you can see from a ERC-721 validator site, there are multiple criteria for you to filter upon.

There are functions like ownerOf, and interfaces such as tokenUri that can come in handy in this filtering. ERC-721 standard [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)